# Partial Match Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Azure Cognitive Search

```
{
      "name": "projectId",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    }
```

I have an Index with a string field ,  that holds  an id e.g.  ABC1234

when I query like this I get no results?

search=/.*1234./&$queryType=full&$count=true&$searchMode=any

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add more context as to which Azure service you're using. At face value, this could be an App Insights, Log Analytics, CosmosDB or many other resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The error is in your regex. The last '.' matches any character (except for line terminators).

Just add a '*' at the end, it will match tokens:

[image]